# Find the integral that includes many level exponents

Tags: real-analysis

I tried without success the method by substitution and integration by parts in finding the integral, $$\int e^{-x-e^{-x}} dx.$$

Can somebody provide any tip or propose a solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: This integral does not have a closed form solution. You will need power series or numerical methods.

Comment: @EthanBolker That is demonstrably false. In reality, the derivative of $e^{-e^{-x}}$ is the integrand of the exercise.

Comment: @Angel Indeed. I jumped hastily to a false conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that you can write the integrand as $e^{-x}\cdot e^{-e^{-x}}$. Then use the substitution $u = -e^{-x}$. The rest is a straightforward calculation.

Comment: Thanks. It solved the issue.